# Why does my bootstrap carousel have extra space on the sides?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly certain that this is a simple fix, but I've spent hours on it and am not sure why I haven't been able to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My HTML is standard bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container" id="main">
        <div class=col-md-12>
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
            <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="*IMAGE*" alt="Power Grid">
                        <div class="carousel-caption"> 
                            <h3>HELLO</h3>
                            <p>World</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="*IMAGE*" alt="Power Grid">
                        <div class="carousel-caption"> 
                            <h3>GOODBYE</h3>
                            <p>World</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my current CSS:

```
#main.container {
    padding: 0 10% 5% 10%;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img { 
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}

#carousel-example-generic {
    border: #000000 solid 10px; 
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Your question should be self-sufficient. In other words, it should be complete without needing to reference any third party links. Your website reference may be useful now, but once your issue is resolved, it won't be useful at all. Consider removing the link or making it less prominent in your question. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask